# Ошибка Func в декомпилированном коде

Tags: c#

```
private static Func<KeyValuePair<double, PrintLevelDetails>, double> func_0;
...
func_0 = new Func<KeyValuePair<double, PrintLevelDetails>, double>(null, (IntPtr) smethod_0);
...
private static double smethod_0(KeyValuePair<double, PrintLevelDetails>   keyValuePair_0)
{
  return keyValuePair_0.Key;
}
```

Ошибка в декомпилированном коде:

> CS0428 Cannot convert method group 'smethod_0' to non-delegate type
>   'System.IntPtr'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то? Декомпилятор декомпилировал что-то не (вполне) правильно.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании делегата в IL обычно используется его конструктор, принимающий пару аргументов (object, IntPtr) - объект и указатель на его метод.

В коде на C# вместо этого следует использовать форму `object.Method` (в случае статического метода - вместо object можно писать класс или не писать ничего если это метод текущего класса):

```
func_0 = smethod_0
```

или

```
func_0 = НеВашКласс.smethod_0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш декомпилятор ошибся.

Попробуйте сделать вручную:

```
func_0 = kvp => kvp.Key;
```